# How to properly partition my HDD for Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Laptop. I don't have any other OS's installed on it. I have tried "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", but that always crashed. So, I chose "Something else" , but I have no idea what to do there. My laptop has a 1 TB HDD with 8 GB of RAM
Edit: I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: You haven't said why your attempted install(s) crashed, but did you verify your download & write to install media? as if you didn't and that's the cause, it'll fail on something-else most likely also, so providing the error message you got maybe easier than attempting to install using 'something else'. Possibly useful : https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck   You also didn't tell us your release (some releases auto-check, others don't..)

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-desktop/13618/2
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-ubuntu-server/13949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice installation guide on https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-20-04-lts-installation-steps-screenshots/, though I would suggest that, if you want to have a separate `/home`partition, make it bigger than in the guide.
However, there is today no need for a separate `/home` partition. If you want a `/home` partition I would suggest the following partition scheme:

```
Device     Name                  Type  Mount point  Size
/dev/sda1 "EFI system partition" fat32 /boot/efi    100MB
/dev/sda2                        Ext4  /            100GB
/dev/sda3                        swap               4GB
/dev/sda4                        Ext4  /home        what's left
```

But, as said, there is no need for a specific `/home` unless you plan on trying out other Linux distributions and want to preserve your files when you change distribution. Then you can use this scheme:

```
Device     Name                  Type  Mount point  Size
/dev/sda1 "EFI system partition" fat32 /boot/efi    100MB
/dev/sda2                        swap               4GB
/dev/sda3                        Ext4  /            what's left
```

I personally have the following (I have a separate disk for `/home` and `/opt`):

Disk 1 250GB

```
Device     Name                  Type  Mount point  Size
/dev/sda1 "EFI system partition" fat32 /boot/efi    100MB
/dev/sda2                        Ext4  /boot        500MB
/dev/sda3                        swap               4GB
/dev/sda4                        Ext4  /            what's left
```

Disk 2 2TB

```
/dev/sdb1                        Ext4  /home        1.5TB
/dev/sdb2                        Ext4  /opt         0.5TB
```

But then I have worked with programming very large software projects, so I needed the large `/home` and a lot of extras that I stored in `/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

"Erase disk and install Ubuntu" is supposed to work and it would be probably then also crash if choose the other option. Maybe there is an issue with the bootstick, you could check the md5 sum of your downloaded .iso file and maybe create a new bootstick.

Comment: Well I'm actually looking for a way to properly partition my hard drive. I don't want to install Ubuntu using the erase disk option.